# What do you call the outer side of a hand?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the outer side of a hand (as opposed to a palm, the inner side)?

Comment: The palm side is also called palmar, and ventral. The opposite, back side, can be called dorsal.     https://study.com/learn/lesson/anatomical-directional-terminology-limbs-hands-feet.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would refer to the **back** of the hand, a description that gives rise to the word **backhander**.

The term carries several negative meanings apart from the literal one of using the back of the hand to strike someone, or using a backhand shot in racquet sports.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/backhander

Comment: Also the positive expression "to know X like the back of your hand".

Comment: When I was a boy, strict fathers used to threaten their children by saying e.g. 'If you don't stop doing that, I'll show you the back of my hand'. Of course 'show' was used figuratively.